# Как пройтись по векторам в мап и, если длина вектора больше 1, вывести ключ ?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main(){

    freopen("input.txt","r+",stdin); 
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout); 
    int nAccounts;
    std::cin >> nAccounts;

    std::string accountName;
    std::getline(std::cin, accountName);

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > account;

    for (int i = 0; i <nAccounts; i++) {
        std::string accountName;
        std::getline(std::cin, accountName);
        account[accountName].push_back(accountName);
        }

    return 0; 
    }
```

**Как пройтись по векторам в мап и, если длина вектора больше 1, вывести ключ ?**

> ```
> Пример входных\выходных данных:
> 5
> abc
> bdf
> abc
> f
> f
> Выходные данные:
> abc
> f 
> или 
> f
> abc
> т.е. порядок вывода не важен.
> ```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то?

    for (std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::iterator it=account.begin(); it !=account.end(); it++)
        if(it->second.size() > 1) std::cout << it->first << std::endl;

Comment: @alexlz: вы бы использовали `auto`, а то совершенно ТСа от STL отпугнёте :)

Comment: @alexlz:

1. Ну, чем меньше низкоуровневых конструкций, тем меньше багов
2. Угу, C++11, так 2013 год на дворе! Пора во всю использовать.

Comment: @VladD 

1. Тогда, может лучше сразу отказаться от C++?

2. Это к мейнтенерам ubuntu. У меня 12.04 с gcc-4.6.3. А ставить самому -- ну честное слово -- неохота.

Comment: @alexlz:

1. Не, поезд ушёл, начальству/заказчикам уже не объяснишь, они все хотят исключительно C++. (Хотя работа со строками в C — тот ещё подарок.)
2. stackoverflow [советует](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8403820/276994) `-std=c++0x` (или `-std=c++11`) для gcc 4.6

Comment: @VladD про то, что между 98 и 2011 есть ещё 2003, я как-то забыл (да и не шибко интересовался). Спасибо.

Comment: @alexlz , @VladD 
Спасибо Вам, не совсем с авто разобрался, но другой вариант пошел на ура, все остальные задачи так же пошли на ура :)

Comment: @arukasa мой вариант с auto:

    for (auto& kv : account)
        if (kv.second.size() > 1) std::cout << kv.first << std::endl;

Правда у меня с g++ v4.6.3 при трансляции надо указывать ключ -std=c++0x Про другие трансляторы ничего не скажу.

А auto -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: @alexlz 
Уже разобрался и с авто, действительно удобно :)
вместо: 
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::iterator it=account.begin()
всего лишь: 
auto it=account.begin()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C++ обойти любой контейнер можно при помощи конструкции

```
for (auto& val : container)
{
    //...
}
```

Для `std::map` `val` будет парой из ключа (строки) и значения (вектора):

```
for (auto& kv : container)
{
    auto& key = kv.first;
    auto& vec = kv.second;
    //...
}
```

Как протестировать длину вектора и вывести ключ, думаю, объяснять не надо.